# Phosphoethanolamine for dogs

Tags: dogs, medicines

Does anyone have experience giving Phosphoethanolamine for dogs? Ferreira et alli mention a concentration of 35 and 70 mg/kg in their [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22213293).

This would translate into 2 capsules for a dog weighing 20 kg. Does anyone know of potential side effects or contraindications for canines?

Comment: i think you shuld talk to a vet about this,a cure for cancer is a little outside the knowledge of the common people here on this site.wellcome to pets,i think you need to talk to a specialist in canine cancer to get the information you are seeking.

Comment: @Vera, we may or may not have experts who can address your question.  It seems like you have already done some research, if you don't get an answer, you are encouraged to post your own answer after doing more research.  This will help others with similar questions, in the future.

Comment: This is considered alternative medicine, BTW. Mainstream veterinary medicine offers chemotherapy to extend quality of life for a few weeks in case of aggressive canine cancer. Hence, I am here seeking experiential knowledge.

Comment: @vera I'm also doing some research about it and I'm wondering if you ended up using it and/or if you have new information to share. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. My dog was diagnosed on June 1st 2018. The vet expected in two to three months he would be much worse and maybe dead. We started it on June 20th. Only on February 27th 2019 he showed discomfort and on the 28th, pain. That was his last day. It seems to me it helped extend his quality of life.